# getJSON not working to collect the ip information

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to use [geoip-json](http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json) to collect information about IP-addresses,
but `getJSON()` is not working.

Here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function(data) {
        $('#ipaddr').html('My IP Address is: ' + data.host);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Working Fine http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/95Tqc/. Make sure you are loading jQuery Library . Also check console fore errors .